# Convert bytearray that contains uint16bit and uint8bit to decimal using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, decimal

I am struggling to convert this data:

```
**b"\x03\x1b\x55\x0f"**
```

into 3 decimal values, the first 2 is 8bit which are 3 and 27
while the other 2 i want to convert to 16bit which would result to 0xf55 (decimal = 3925)

how can i do this in python3?
im stuck here

```
val = binascii.unhexlify(val)
val = array.array("B",val)
```

this will result to [3,27,85,15] or [0x03,0x1b,0x55,0x0f] if the array is hex.

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, found the answer

it is 
(256 * 15) + 85

Answer (score 0):

The Python code to solve this problem is:

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> ans = unpack('<bbh', b'\x03\x1b\x55\x0f')
>>> print(ans)
(3, 27, 3925)
```

The leading '<' indicates that the bytes when representing a word/dword are little endian.